# Expo SDK 45 splash screen with react navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I just upgraded to Expo SDK 45 and i got a warning: "expo-app-loading is deprecated in favor of expo-splash-screen: use SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() and SplashScren.hideAsync() instead. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/. So I did and followed the link provided.

The problem I have now is that in the example they call onLayOutRootView on the onLayOut of the root view. Now I'm using react-navigation so my root view is nested quite deep into my application.

Do I have to pass this function down to the root view or is there a way to pass this function to one of my providers/navigationcontainer? Or any other fix?

```
//imports


export default App = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const scheme = "dark";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        // Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
        await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (appIsReady) {
    return (
      <StripeProvider publishableKey={PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={scheme === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
          <StatusBar barStyle={scheme === "dark" ? "light-content" : "dark-content"} />
          <OrderProvider>
            <CartProvider>
              <FavoriteProvider>
                <FirebaseProvider>
                  <UserProvider>
                    <NavigationContainer
                      theme={scheme === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme}
                      ref={navigationRef}
                    >
                      <RootStackScreens on/>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                  </UserProvider>
                </FirebaseProvider>
              </FavoriteProvider>
            </CartProvider>
          </OrderProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StripeProvider>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Bert - having the same issue haha just getting to expo 45. I've just dropped the whole callback. I was getting "SplashScreen.show has already been called" and just hiding the real return behind a if isReady.  - i hope someone else has something better to contribute haha

Comment: The answer marked works for me :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try wrap everything in a `View` with `flex:1`.

Something like this:

```
...imports...
import { View } from "react-native";
    
export default App = () => {

 ...code...

 const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
  if (appIsReady) {
   await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }
 }, [appIsReady]);
    
 if (!appIsReady) {
  return null;
 }
    
 return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
   <StripeProvider publishableKey={PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
     ...
   </StripeProvider>
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! thank you.

Comment: Strange, it did remove the loading but then the app was not loaded at all and/or crashed x) (doesn't happen with expo-app-loading)

Answer (score 20):

As the question uses `NavigationContainer`, I think the best approach would be to follow [expo's instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/#splashscreenpreventautohideasync), but modify the function's 'return' to pass `onLayoutRootView` to the `NavigationContainer` and not to a `View`, as follows:

```
return (
...
  <NavigationContainer
    theme={scheme === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme}
    ref={navigationRef}
    onReady={onLayoutRootView} // <-- HERE!
  >
     <RootStackScreens on/>
  </NavigationContainer>
...
)
```

This answer is based on [this code example](https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/stuck-on-apploading-splashscreen-page-when-published-or-on-testflight/12702/2).

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I think this should be the accepted answer because it is more in line with both the intended use of the navigation package as well as Expo's instructions.

Comment: thanks! indeed as @buechel said, this should be the proper answer given does not include an extra View there

Answer (score 6):

Just call set NavigationContainer  onReady to onLayoutRootView

```
 <NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView}>
    <NavigatorDrawer />
 </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my codes which work on my App. I copy the most of them from official document https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/ and implement

```js
<NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView}>
  {children}// its children
</NavigationContainer>
```

[image]